# multidimensional array push in PHP

Tags: php, php-7

```
    <?php
$userData = [
    [
        "UID" => "5f10482574d83d4b726fe5",
        "name" => "Yug Gill",
        "orgID" => "5f10481d74d83d4b726",
        "imageURL" => "female.png"
    ]
];

$userProductsData = [
    [
    "UPID" => "5f10482574d83d4b6fe007",
    "UID" => "5f10482574d83d4b726fe5",
    ]
];
$userDetailsResult = [];
foreach ($userData as $key => $value) {
    $userData[$key]["UPID"] = $userProductsData[$value["UID"]] ?? [];
}
```

> Expected Output

```
$userData = [
    [
        "UID" => "5f10482574d83d4b726fe5",
        "name" => "Yug Gill",
        "orgID" => "5f10481d74d83d4b726",
        "imageURL" => "female.png",
        "UPID" => "5f10482574d83d4b6fe007"
    ]
];
```

i have two aray `UID` common for both array, now i want to take UPID from `$userProductsData` and push into `$userData`, i have tried not working properly, kindly anyone update my code please
?>

Comment: `$userProductsData[$value["UID"]]` becomes `$userProductsData['5f10482574d83d4b726fe5']`, and there is no element by that key in that array.

Comment: loop each `$userProductsData`, then inside loop each `$userData`, then use an `if`

Comment: Why ```$userDetailsResult = [];``` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one.

```
$userData = [
    [
        "UID" => "5f10482574d83d4b726fe5",
        "name" => "Yug Gill",
        "orgID" => "5f10481d74d83d4b726",
        "imageURL" => "female.png"
    ]
];

$userProductsData = [
    [
    "UPID" => "5f10482574d83d4b6fe007",
    "UID" => "5f10482574d83d4b726fe5",
    ]
];
$userDetailsResult = [];

foreach ($userProductsData as $key => $value) {
    $userData[$key]["UPID"] = $value['UPID'];
   
}

print_r($userData);
```

Comment: single loop we cannot achieve this ?

Comment: What do you mean by single loop? It is because of the 2 foreach loops? If that's the case, you can actually remove the first foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$userProductsData` is a regular array, it has indexes 0, 1, 2 etc... Then you are trying to get an item from this array by string key `"5f10482574d83d4b726fe5"`.

`$userProductsData` should be a key array like that:

```
$userProductsData = [
    "5f10482574d83d4b726fe5" => [
        "UPID" => "5f10482574d83d4b6fe007",
        "UID" => "5f10482574d83d4b726fe5",
    ],
];
```

Then you can get an item from this array by key `"5f10482574d83d4b726fe5"`.